# Kotlin yield example

Tags: kotlin, sequence, yield, iterable

I am learning Kotlin and for the love of it, I cannot get the yield/sequence straight. Could someone please correct my code?

```kotlin
fun Sequence<Int>.mapIterable(transform: (Int)->Int) = sequence {
    this.forEach({ x -> yield(transform(x)) })
}

fun Sequence<Int>.product(): Int {
    return this.reduce({ acc,x -> acc*x })
}

infix fun Int.powerof(exponent: Int): Int {
    return (1..exponent).mapIterable({ x -> this }).product()
}

fun main() {
    println(2 powerof 10)
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Why are you trying to write a `mapIterable` when there is already `map`? How do you want `mapIterable` to be different from `map`?

Comment: I would like a version of map that returns an iterator and not a List greedily.

Comment: Umm `Sequence.map` *is* lazy.

Comment: You saying (1..exponent).map(...) which returns a List<T> returns an iterable?

Comment: It's `(1..exponent).asSequence().map(...)`. Otherwise you would call the `map` that returns a `List`.

Comment: Yees! asSequence! This solves my problem, at least partially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mapIterable` doesn't compile because `this` is referring to the receiver of the `sequence { ... }` lambda, which is a `SequenceScope<Int>`. This `SequenceScope` is what allows you to call `yield`. What you meant is the receiver of `mapIterable`, which you can write as `this@mapIterable`.

Note that `mapIterable` is just reinventing [`Sequence.map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/map.html). Just use `map` instead.

`product` is fine, but using `reduce` means that this throws an exception when the sequence is empty. I would write this with `fold`:

```
fun Sequence<Int>.product() = fold(1, Int::times)
```

In `powerOf`, `(1..exponent)` is not a `Sequence<Int>`, but an `IntRange`. You can convert it to a `Sequence<Int>` using [`asSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/as-sequence.html):

```
(1..exponent).asSequence().map { x -> this }.product()
```

An alternative way is [`generateSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/generate-sequence.html) to generate an infinite sequence of `this`, and then `take(exponent)`.

```
infix fun Int.powerOf(exponent: Int) =
    generateSequence { this }.take(exponent).product()
```

That said, doing things lazily here isn't really much better than just creating a `IntArray(exponent) { this }`. The highest exponent you can meaningfully compute with this method is 31 (2^31 and you already reached the max value of `Int`). 31 integers in an array isn't that much.

Comment: For the sake of argument, lets assume exponent is 1 billion. The product will not be meaningful but that is not the point. The Array is then going to use up a lot of memory. And if those ints are boxed, its even worse, right? EDIT Ah IntArray is a primitive array, please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper suggested:

```kotlin
fun Sequence<Int>.product(): Int {
    return this.reduce({ acc,x -> acc*x })
}

infix fun Int.powerof(exponent: Int): Int {
    return (1..exponent).asSequence().map({ this }).product()
}

fun main() {
    println(2 powerof 10)
}
```